# First riddle that I did create:What am I?

Tags: riddle

This is my first riddle.

> I am once in a minute, but 2 times in the millennium. What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are

> Either the letter m, n or i

Comment: There's a third option as well :)

Comment: @jafe oops. I wrote that before but idk why i edited it out XD

Comment: Well technically, a millennium is **a thousand years**, which does not quite fit...

Comment: user477343 will not get the check because you typed all the answers

Comment: @hahaboki yes, this answer deserves the check most definitely!

Comment: Welcome haha. I have yet to post a good riddle here though. It's more fun cracking them XD

Comment: just eatin' kitkat 'n' lookin' your answers

Comment: @hahaboki no problemo! Just letting you know, this riddle is an ultimate classic. It would be quite a**m**az**in**g (pun intended) if you are the one who invented it :D

Comment: There is fourth option.

Answer (score 3):

You are

> the letter **M**,

because

> you are literally once in a **m**inute and twice in a **m**illeniu**m**.

Also,

> the question "What am I?" serves a hint, as it sounds like "What **m** I?"

---

Credit to @[R.D](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/51604/r-d), the answer could also be

> **n** or **i**. [@R.D's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70348/first-riddle-that-i-did-createwhat-am-i/70351#70351) deserves the check, not mine!

Comment: just have to wait 12 mins...

Comment: @hahaboki thank you! But 2 things: 1. the answer above is also correct, and 2. are you sure you created this riddle? I have seen and heard this riddle before...

Comment: @hahaboki Why not 'i' or 'n'?  Or 'm&i' or 'm&n' or 'i&n'?  Or 'min'?  Not clear on what makes the 'm' stand out as correct.

Comment: @hagfy I heard of this riddle before, and usually the answer is what I wrote. I think the answer above deserves the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Another answer:

> It is the letter **E**. Appears once in a "minut**e**", 2 times in "th**e** mill**e**nium".

Comment: @hahaboki You might want to read it again... (i.e. I am once in **a minute** and twice in **the millennium**.) So although this answer may not be correct, it is not wrong either... :P